# getting values of attributes of dynamically generated elements (through ajax) in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am generating values into a table through ajax. This values are  s.
inside this roles there is an anchor that which would be in all this roles. This anchor tags have a class which I use to reference it with javascript.

The anchor tag in this roles have  an onclick function referencing a javascript method, I am trying to use this method to get one of the attribute of the clicked anchor tag.
But unfortunately I get the undefined error, when I click on the anchor tags in the role.

```
    <tr>

 <td>
                        <a href="#" onClick="JavaScript:filltransfercombo();" class="btn btn-default transferchat" data-operatorid="@avisitor.OperatorID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#transferModal" title="Transfer chat">
                            <img src="~/Content/images/chaticons/transfer.png" height="20" width="20" />
                        </a>
                    </td>

</tr>
```

My intension is to collect this attribute --  data-operatorid. I want to use it for some manipulations in my javascript.

My javascript is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function filltransfercombo() {


            var result = "";
            var active = $('a').index(this);
            var currentoperatorid = $(active).attr("data-operatorid"); //This is the id of the currently attending operator

            console.log(currentoperatorid);

        }

</script>
```

Comment: I think you're confusing jQuery and ajax.

Comment: how do you mean @SimpleJ

Comment: I tried to use the on() method in jquery to get the attribute of currently click element. But on method did not trigger. So I felt I should use javascript

Comment: I mean it looks like you're using static html, and I don't see any ajax requests being made in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` event does not need the `javascript:` notation... You would put it in case you were setting the method on `href`.

Also, from `onclick` event you would have access to the `this` variable, not from the method. You can, however, pass it as an argument, so:

```
<a href="#" onClick="filltransfercombo(this);" class="btn btn-default transferchat" data-operatorid="@avisitor.OperatorID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#transferModal" title="Transfer chat">
```

and js:

```
function filltransfercombo(sender) {
    var result = "";
    var currentoperatorid = $(sender).attr("data-operatorid"); //This is the id of the currently attending operator

    console.log(currentoperatorid);

}
```

Comment: You just saved me one hour of coding.

Comment: Thanks alot. It works like magic and everything just goes on well. You are the boomb brother. I am grateful.  @LcSalazar

Comment: If the attribute is a `data..` tag, wouldn't it be a bit more efficient/correct to use `$(sender).data("operatorid");`?

Comment: @entropic, that's an interesting point... There are many discussions about both performances... See http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-attr/22

Comment: @LcSalazar that is a fantastic site - no idea it existed.  Very interesting indeed...

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with jQuery.

Remove the "onClick" attribute on your anchors and instead bind a click function to the anchor tags (within the table only). Then add your processing code within that function.

Do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr td a').click(function() {
        var result = "";
        var currentoperatorid = $(this).data("operatorid"); //This is the id of the currently attending operator

        console.log(currentoperatorid);
    });
});
</script>
```

Natrually, you need to make sure the jQuery javascript library is also included on this page.